# Call object recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new with Javascript. I have a javascript class with calling recursive inside.
But when running I got an error :

> $(...).display is not a function at $(item).display(false);

this is my code:

```
function ScopeData(table, parentRow) {
const tableData = table;
const scopeEl = parentRow;
var childScope = [];
var childRows = [];

this.display = function aa(isDisplay) {
    childRows.each(function (index, el) {
        if (isDisplay) {
            $(el).removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else {
            $(el).addClass("hidden");
        }
    });

    if (!isDisplay) {
        var display1 = this.display;
        for (let i = 0; i < childScope.length; i++) {
            const item = $(childScope)[i];
            $(item).display(false);
        }
    }
}

this.findChildRow = function () {
    var scope = $(scopeEl).data("scope")
    childRows = $(tableData).find("tr[data-parent='" + scope + "']");
}

this.createChildScope = function () {

    $(childRows).each(function (index, el) {
        var scope = $(el).data("scope")
        if (scope !== "" && scope !== undefined) {

            var childRows = $(tableData).find("tr[data-parent='" + scope + "']");
            var dataRow = new ScopeData(table, $(el));
            dataRow.init();

            childScope.push(dataRow);
        }
    });
}

this.init = function () {
    var display = this.display;
    this.findChildRow();

    this.createChildScope();

    $(scopeEl).find("i").on("click", function () {
        display(false);
    })
}
```

}

Please help me fix the issue.
Thank in advance

Comment: Did you mean `$(item).toggle(false);`?  Are you trying to show/hide the item using jquery's show/hide/toggle, or recursively trying to call your own `display()` function, which you've not added as a plugin/extension to jquery, so won't work under the `$` object

Comment: You probably need to include jQuery library to fix this.

Comment: Hi. I fixed with changing      $(item).display(false)  to   item.display(false);. It seems wrapped with jquery caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to javascript and how `this` keyword is evaluated. I highly recommend reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) before proceeding as it is one of javascript core concepts. One hacky way to solve your problem is:

Assign the `this` into a variable and use that instead.

```
function ScopeData(table, parentRow) {
    var self = this;
    ...
    this.init = function () {
      var display = self.display;
```

One cleaner way to do this, is binding the function which is supported by any modern browser.

```
this.display = function aa(isDisplay) {
    childRows.each(function (index, el) {
        if (isDisplay) {
            $(el).removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else {
            $(el).addClass("hidden");
        }
    });

    if (!isDisplay) {
        var display1 = this.display;
        for (let i = 0; i < childScope.length; i++) {
            const item = $(childScope)[i];
            $(item).display(false);
        }
    }
}

this.display = this.display.bind(this);
```

Comment: @ Pelelis: Thanks for your help. I fixed the issue.